# Batch file is not going to the the current folder in %1

Tags: batch-file, arguments

I have the following batch file: (name: u.bat)

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\Uedit32.exe"  %1
rem exit
```

I run the batch file in the temp folder to open an existing "readme.txt"

```
c:\temp> u readme.txt
```

What is happening is the app is trying to open *readme.txt* in the *C:\Program Files ....\UltraEdit* directory and not the *C:\temp* directory.

How do I tell the batch file %1 is in the current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the PATH,

> Syntax
>
> Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.
>
> START ["title"] [/Dpath] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
>   [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL] 
>   [/WAIT] [/B] [command/program] [parameters]

path    Starting directory

Comment: This worked:start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\Uedit32.exe" /D.\%1

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to UltraEdit, but what you can do is include `%~dp0` to get the current drive and path, like so

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\Uedit32.exe" .\%1
rem exit
```

or

```
@echo off
start "" /D . "C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\Uedit32.exe" %1
rem exit
```

Comment: I tried both of them, it'll now try to find the readme.txt in c:\utils where the u.bat file is.

Comment: Your are correct, it is indeed taking the path of the script called. Take the . as parameter, to get the current directory

Answer (score 0):

This should also work and allow you to open more than one file:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\Uedit32.exe"  "%~f1" "%~f2" "%~f3" "%~f4" "%~f5"
```

But you will probably find that this also works and the cmd window will close:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\Uedit32.exe"  %*
```